# Minimum and maximum of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Fixed two integers $n>1$ and $N\geq 2$, consider the (finite) sequence of points
$$
S:=\left\{ \frac{\ln^{k}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{k}(N)}{\ln^{k+1}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{k+1}(N)} : k=0,\ldots, n-1  \right\}
$$

I am interested in computing the minimum and the maximum of $S$, Some suggestions?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $N = 2$, it's straight-forward that the first term (with $k = 0$) and the last term (with $k = n-1$) are the maximum and the minimum of $S$.

We will prove the same result for $N \ge 3$:
$$\frac{\ln^{p}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{p}(N)}{\ln^{p+1}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{p+1}(N)} \ge \frac{\ln^{q}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{q}(N)}{\ln^{q+1}(2)+\ldots + \ln^{q+1}(N)} \qquad \forall 0\le p<q \tag{1}$$

Let's denote
$$f(x) = \ln\left(\sum_{n=2}^N \ln^x(n)  \right) \qquad \forall 0\le p<q $$

$(1)$ is equivalent to
$$f(p)-f(p+1) \ge f(q)-f(q+1) \iff f(p)+f(q+1) \ge f(q)+f(p+1)  \qquad \forall 0\le p<q \tag{2}$$

**We prove $(2)$ by applying the [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality).**

For $N \ge 3$, we have
$$f'(x) = \frac{\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\ln(\ln(n))\ln^x(n)\right)}{\sum_{n=2}^N \ln^x(n)} >0$$
$$f''(x) =  \frac{\left(\sum_{n=2}^N (\ln(\ln(n))^2\ln^x(n))\right)\left(\sum_{n=2}^N \ln^x(n)\right)-\left(\sum_{n=2}^N (\ln(\ln(n))\ln^x(n))\right)^2}
{\left(\sum_{n=2}^N \ln^x(n)\right)^2} \tag{3}$$
By applying the [Cauchy Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#%E2%84%9Dn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space), the numerator of $(3)$ is positive. Then $f''(x) > 0$.

Hence, the function $f(x)$ is increasing and convexe for $x \in \Bbb R^+$. Applying the Karamata's inequality for $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) = (q+1,p,q,p+1)$ that satisfy
$$x_1 > x_2$$
$$y_1 \ge y_2$$
$$x_1+x_2 = y_1+y_2 = (p+q+1)$$

then $(2)$ holds true.

**Conclusion:** the first term (with $k = 0$) and the last term (with $k = n-1$) are the maximum and the minimum of $S$.